# Filter Combobox of a column in Sharepoint ListA based on toggle of Sharepoint ListB. Power apps

Tags: combobox, filtering, powerapps, power-platform

I have 2 sharepoint lists: ListA and ListB. ListA has column for Names which is a text field and ListB has a column for if a student is there or not there (Yes/No) which is a toggle field.I have a combobox that displays the names in names column of ListA, but I want the names in the combobox to be based on if the student is there or not there (from the yes/no column). If the item has yes for the column then certain names will be displayed and if it is no then the other names will be displayed.I also have a toggle next to the combobox that should control this. If the toggle is on (that means in the there/not there column which is in ListB, the value is yes otherwise it’s no)

I would also like to note, I have a column called StudentID as text field in both lists that have the same values. So this could be used a connector.

Here is the code I used:

Filter(Students, StudentID in Filter(‘additional information’, Toggle=Toggle1.Value).StudentID).‘First, Last’

There is an error that power apps can’t convert text to record. But the StudentID column has field type as test in both lists.

I get a red squiggly line under the first StudentID.
note: StudentID is a text field in the first list and the same name is given to the column in the second list 2. In both lists it is a text field.

Any ideas on what’s wrong here?
Thanks !